# Console error: UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm new to `UICollectionView` and I'm following a tutorial that I found on Youtube, but i'm stuck on an error I can't figure out.

When I run the app with this code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

        return 1;

    }

    -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        return [self.array count];

    }

    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        CollectionCell *aCell = (CollectionCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        aCell.title.text = self.array[indexPath.row];

        return aCell;

    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.array = @[@"First", @"Second", @"Thirth", @"Fourth"];

    }
```

And in the .h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *array;
```

In the console I receive the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
```

Im NOT using storyboard, and custom maked the CollectionView what you can see here:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas why i'm getting this error? Everything is welcome!

edit:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.array = @[@"First", @"Second", @"Thirth", @"Fourth"];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flow setItemSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)];
    [flow setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flow];

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is an error while registering the uicollectionviewcell view class. To resolve put the below line in your code:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
```

Comment: have you put the code like this: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[FotoCell class]
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *myLayout = [[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init]autorelease];
    [myLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:myLayout];

}

Comment: error is here:- CollectionCell *aCell = (CollectionCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: UICollectionViewCell *aCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Answer (score 2):

Register Collection cell in `viewDidLoad` method ::

```
[self.collView registerClass:[mineCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
```

Try this after above line:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flow setItemSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)];
[flow setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

[self.collView setCollectionViewLayout:flow];
```

Here, `mineCell` is my custom collectionViewCell or you can use `[UICollectionViewCell class]`directly.

Thanks.

Comment: After putting your code in the viewDidLoad method the error won't disappear? It still gives me the same error.