# Adding UICollectionViewController's view to a super view "programmatically"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to do a simple task of adding a UICollectionView to the main view, programmatically.

I first created a "PhotosViewController.h/h/xib" files (of type UIViewController), removed the view that was given and added a **UICollectionView** as the primary view of this controller & then changed the superclass of "PhotosViewController.h" to UICollectionViewController.

I followed the first 6 steps given in this tutorial: **http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial** and then jumped to step 14. What I am trying to do is just to bring up this view when the user clicks on a segmented control button.

```
if ([segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex]==3){
    //Photos View Controller
    pvc=[[PhotosViewController alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Photos segment is chosen!");
    [[self view] addSubview:pvc.view]; **//Line 5**
}
```

But the program throws up an exception on reaching **Line 5**.

This is the log message that I get.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
```

Looks like, I am missing something very fundamental here. I have been searching for any kind of solution to this problem for  the past one hour and I couldn't find anything.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15270058/352891

Comment: Please add collectionView code, flowLayout, datasource and delegate code.

Comment: @user352891 No, it didn't

Comment: @iOS10 I did add the datasource code. Delegate, flowLayout and collectionView doesn't have any required methods in their protocol, everything is optional. So I don't think that this causes the problem. Moreover, I followed the above tutorial and before even adding the datasource methods, the program runs fine. It shows a blank view with gray background. That's what I am trying to achieve here as well.

The problem I'm facing is due to the  addSubView call. Any help on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[PhotosViewController alloc] init];
```

I assume this is where you are creating your collection view controller. The designated initialiser for this class is [`initWithCollectionViewLayout:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewController/initWithCollectionViewLayout%3a), where you'd pass in a layout object. You aren't passing one in, so it complains. Try using that initialiser, or, in your subclass, make sure you call this instead of [super init], and pass in a new flow layout object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on where you initialized your collection view, but it ought to look something like this:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                                                    230.0f,
                                                                    [self viewWidth],
                                                                    [self viewHeight]) 
                                    collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

Unless you have a more extended UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

From the message you're getting, it looks as though you're not giving it a UICollectionViewFlowLayout in your collectionViewLayout:

Comment: I have this code as part of my viewDidLoad method. This is how it looks like, 
'- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200)];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    [[self collectionView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.25f alpha:1.0f]];
}'

Any other hint?