# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios6, uicollectionview

Error signal SIGABRT NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'.

When UITableViewCell is pressed it should display UICollectionView

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UIViewController *viewController;
switch (indexPath.row) {

    case IMAGE: 
        viewController = [[[CollectionViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
 [self.CollectionViewController registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        case PROCEDURAL:
        viewController = [[[ProceduralExampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 
        break;
    default: 
        viewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
} 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Using storyboard file for collection view segue.

How to solve this error **UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter**

Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270058/console-error-uicollectionview-must-be-initialized-with-a-non-nil-layout-parame

Comment: How are you synthesizing your UICollectionView?

Comment: declared the property of uicollectionview in tableviewcontroller not IBOutlet it

Comment: Tried this code like this yesterday - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UIViewController *viewController;switch (indexPath.row) {case IMAGE: 
        viewController = [[[CollectionViewController alloc] init] autorelease];[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"]; but no success

Answer (score 4):

> UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter

Is hopefully self explanatory. The designated initialiser for UICollectionView is

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame collectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout
```

So you need to pass it a layout object. You don't show the code where you make a collection view, but I'm assuming `CollectionViewController` is a `UICollectionViewController` subclass, in which case you need to use this designated initialiser:

```
- (id)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout
```

Currently, you're using `init`.

In both cases you need to create and pass in a layout object when initalising.

If your collection view is held in the storyboard then you need to get it from the storyboard using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`, so your code above would read something like:

```
viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CollectionViewController"];
```

Comment: i m trying to show uicollection view when tableview cell is pressed. I have collection view controller class and storyboard for uicollectionviewcontroller segue. How i can initialize collectionview in tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath. If you can show me that.

Comment: i did added that line now it says Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x7ac55f0>. Should i import mainstoryboard to tableviewcontroller

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about your storyboard or what the identifiers on it are. You need to set up an identifier on your storyboard for the collection view controller or it won't return anything.