# Xcode 5 / iOS 7 setCollectionViewLayout crash

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an App written for iOS 6 that uses UICollectionViewController, the app works fine but when I tried to compile in Xcode 5 I get the error bellow.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'layout cannot be nil in setCollectionViewLayout:'...

I tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270058/console-error-uicollectionview-must-be-initialized-with-a-non-nil-layout-parame) but I keep getting the same error. Any ideas?

```
CollectionViewLayout *layout = [[CollectionViewLayout alloc] init];

self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:ItemIdentifier];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[HeaderCollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];

self.collectionLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(0, 50);
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;

self.collectionView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
self.collectionLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
```

//Stack trace

```
2013-10-01 14:15:37.140 MemberCatalog[10841:a0b] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/UICollectionView.m:2001
2013-10-01 14:15:37.186 MemberCatalog[10841:a0b] Uncaught exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Reason: layout cannot be nil in setCollectionViewLayout:
User Info: (null)
Call Stack: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x031e75e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02c548b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x031e7448 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x0029923e -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   UIKit                               0x00cdeba3 -[UICollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:] + 156
    5   UIKit                               0x00cfcd7b -[UICollectionViewControllerWrapperView didMoveToSuperview] + 462
    6   UIKit                               0x007261a6 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 472
    7   UIKit                               0x00725ef8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 260
    8   UIKit                               0x00731031 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1847
    9   UIKit                               0x00724521 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
    10  UIKit                               0x007d66eb +[UIViewControllerWrapperView wrapperViewForView:wrapperFrame:viewFrame:] + 382
    11  UIKit                               0x0080c867 -[UITabBarController _wrapperViewForViewController:] + 221
    12  UIKit                               0x00813a60 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 441
    13  UIKit                               0x00813262 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 63
    14  UIKit                               0x0080f64b -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 279
    15  UIKit                               0x0080f470 -[UITabBarController setSelectedIndex:] + 261
    16  MemberCatalog                   0x000aa9f8 -[MainViewController updateTabBar:] + 584
    17  MemberCatalog                   0x000ab872 -[MainViewController showCategory::] + 3538
    18  MemberCatalog                   0x000abe30 -[MainViewController menuButtonTap:] + 1296
    19  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02c66874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    20  UIKit                               0x006cac8c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    21  UIKit                               0x006cac18 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    22  UIKit                               0x007c26d9 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    23  UIKit                               0x007c2a9c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    24  UIKit                               0x007c1d4b -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    25  UIKit                               0x007080cd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    26  UIKit                               0x00708d34 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
    27  UIKit                               0x006dca36 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    28  UIKit                               0x006c6d9f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x031708af __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x0317023b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0318d30e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0318cb33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0318c94b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    34  GraphicsServices                    0x03c6a9d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    35  GraphicsServices                    0x03c6a7fe GSEventRun + 104
    36  UIKit                               0x006c994b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    37  MemberCatalog                       0x000033e6 main + 134
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x0395a725 start + 0
```

Comment: Standard request: full error message, backtrace, surrounding code.

Comment: add code of your .m when you build your collection view

Comment: Hi John, how are you instantiating the value "layout" that you pass into your collectionView init method?

Comment: CollectionViewLayout *layout = [[CollectionViewLayout alloc] init];

Comment: Can you add an exception breakpoint (breakpoints navigatior --> add --> exception breakpoint) and confirm that it is crashing on the line above? It looks from the trace like you are setting the collection view layout again somewhere else (it refers to setCollectionViewLayout rather than initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:) so we might be looking at the wrong code here.

Comment: I've been looking for setCollectionViewLayout but there is not setCollectionViewLayout in the code.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of reports from HockeyApp with the same issue and I can detect the line of code and the layout that's being created.

The weird thing is that this is only happening in 7.0.x, no 7.1 crashes so far, so I'm assuming this might be related to iOS itself.

Answer (score -1):

please remove this line: 
self.collectionLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(0, 50);

then, it should works